# Targeting WP 8.0 in VS 2013 Update 2

Tags: windows-phone, visual-studio-2013

I have just installed Visual Studio 2013 Update 2. During yesterday's Keynote, it was said that with this update it would be possible to build both WP 8.0 and WP 8.1 apps. I can still open my older solutions, but cannot create a new Windows Phone 8.0 application - anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: I was going to ask the same question. I cannot target Windows Store 8.0 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution: instead of creating a new Blank App (Windows Phone), one should create a new Blank App (Windows Phone Silverlight). :)

Comment: Well we have an app that should go to the store and we can't create a package. If I go to `project -> store ->` everything is greyed out. I cloned the project, ported it to 8.1 and then it would work. But as 8.1 is not properly out yet we'd like to release it NOW for wp8.0 instead of waiting for the update or, like yuo said, creating a new project :(
Any hints?
It's Visual Studio 2013 Professional Update 2 and Windows 8.1 Professional 64bit.